# Disable .Net framework from server

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, frameworks, windows-server-2012

I have windows server and using as a DB server. What will happen if I disable .Net framework on server?
Note : I'm using SQL jobs to run SSIS pacakges on that server.

Comment: What is your plan to "disable .Net framework"? Make it clear please, as .NET Framework 4.x is part of the operating system and you cannot disable it at all.

Comment: Hi, There are few .Net framework security updates are there. To skip those from future. I'm going to disable it.